# Properly tagging and classifying what Billiard is discussed

Tags: discussion

It came to the attention of a few of us that there may be some ambiguity when refering to Billiards or Cue Sport games

There are Three types of tables cue sport players may play on:

1. Carom Billiards Table (pocketless)
2. Pool Table (pockets)
3. Snooker Table

Each of which has a set of classified games

1. Carom Billiard:

   a. Straight Billiard/Rail

   b. Balkline

   c. Three-Cushion Billiards
2. Pool Table

   a. Eight-Ball

   b. Nine-ball

   c. Straight Pool

   d. Bank Pool

   e. Speed Pool
3. Snooker Table

   a. English Billards

   b. Snooker

Information has been taken off wikipeda cue sports section. Feel free to suggest anything that should be added to this list or requires modification.

**The question is, should the asker specify the table in which the game is played in addition to the name of the game?**
I personally think it's not necessary to specify you're playing i.e. eight-ball on a pool table, but it can't hurt to add one more tag.

The following question is due to the numerous set of professional rules that currently exist (i.e. for 8-ball pool it's APA, BCA, WPA, CPA, VNEA)

**When asking about rules of a particular game, should the asker include what rules?**

Here, I think it's a must

Answer (score 2):

First, in light of this ambiguity, the [pool](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pool) tag has been created with the excerpt, "Questions about the cue sport formally known as pocket billiards or pool billiards."

> The question is, should the asker specify the table in which the game is played in addition to the name of the game?

Depends on your question.

Are you asking rules? Technique? How is eight-ball played? Tournament structure?

From above, "How is eight-ball played?" is the only question that (clearly) merits the specification of game being played, for self-explanatory reasons.

In terms of specifying a table, the tag you add to the question should already (implicitly) address what table you are playing on.

> I personally think it's not necessary to specify you're playing i.e. eight-ball on a pool table, but it can't hurt to add one more tag.

I agree, but I advise against going [tag crazy](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/grounds-of-tag-creation). Are you asking specifically about eight-ball, because your question asks about what rules standard is most widely used in the sport of <strike>billiards</strike> pool? Sure, you can specify what game you're playing, but I'm still not sure if your question would merit that tag. Now, if APA is most common for eight-ball and BCA is most common for nine-ball or something, then the specificity is critical to answer your question. Nonetheless, my point is be specific and concise.

Also, having tags that mean the same thing (ie, pocket-billiards, pool, pool-billiards, etc.) is redundant, and usually eligible for tag synonymization.

> When asking about rules of a particular game, should the asker include what rules?

Usually, yes. At a higher level, pro rules can be different from amateur rules, etc. Unless this is specified, then we, the community, can only assume.

Answer (score -1):

The tag used in the question is much less important than the text of the actual question.  For example, in your question "[What are the most common billiard rules professionals play by?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3818/what-are-the-most-common-billiard-rules-professionals-play-by)," You are asking about the rules of a billiard game, but you haven't specified which game you are interested in.  You added the "pool" tag, but even then, there are lots of games that can be played on a pool table.  This is probably why your question doesn't have an answer yet.

A tag called "billiards" or "cue-sports" or something like that is enough to categorize the question.  (I personally believe that general tags are more important than specific tags.)  But the actual text of the question needs enough information in it to make an answer possible.

Comment: Check for edits, I did specify but an admin removed it. I don't think that's why my question doesn't have an answer yet. This site lacks pool players that follow professional rules. If you look at one of my other [question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3876/what-set-of-rules-say-that-scratching-requires-the-player-to-take-another-ball-o/3878#3878) this guy answered it with house rules he considers "official"

Comment: and I mean prior to me changing its title to straight-pool, I'm refering to the tags.

Comment: @echad Now that you've specified 8-ball in the question, an answer is possible.

Comment: @BenMiller I think echad is on the money when he surmises that the reason his question doesn't have an answer yet is due to the lack of expertise the Sports SE community has in the sport, especially in regards to playing under official rules and standards. Also, you were the one in favor of specification, yet are now backing down and saying "billiards" is enough to tag the question, so which is it? General tags covers a lot of ground and specific tags compliment **when necessary**.

Comment: @edmastermind29 [My comment](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3818/what-are-the-most-common-8-ball-rules-professionals-play-by#comment8222_3818) on the question had nothing to do with the tags.  Until the most recent revision of the question (after I left this answer here), a specific game was not specified.

Comment: Right, but did still ask for specification. So tags, titles, or not, there was still ambiguity. I agree that the question, as it stands, is focused and narrow enough to answer (eight-ball vs. multiple games that fall under "billiards").

Comment: @edmastermind29 Yes, the question needed specification, and now it has it.  My point with this answer is that tags are not the most efficient way to provide that specificity.  A question should provide enough information that you could answer it even if there weren't any tags.  Otherwise, you would need a tag for every single game, which you seem to be against with your answer as well.  I agree completely with your answer; I'm not sure what you disagree with mine on.

Comment: I agree with that, and in addition, [tags should serve to specify and categorize the question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/tagging). The only thing I disagree with about your answer is the statement, "You added the `pool` tag, but even then, there are lots of games that can be played on a pool table. This is probably why your question doesn't have an answer yet." Ambiguity aside, even if this is the case, I think the lack of expertise currently would be more of a reason. I agree with your inquiry about the ambiguity of billiards, which prompted using the `pool` tag.

Comment: Case in point, if this were a cricket question with the expertise we have, there would most likely be requests for clarification (as you did for the billiards question) and answers. I think we're mainly on the same page, but I wasn't entirely clear about where you were coming from.