# Create an "own-goal" tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I've created an [own-goal](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/own-goal) tag as I think it's an interesting aspect in many sports, and also the inclusion of this tag to relevant questions is very intuitive to me. Then I tried to apply this tag to 2 of my questions and 3 other questions on the site:

My questions: (*the tag was removed in both of the questions by user @Ale*)

- [Shot on target with deflection - a goal or an own goal](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15729/shot-on-target-with-deflection-a-goal-or-an-own-goal)
- [Is an own goal scored with hand a valid goal?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15861/is-an-own-goal-scored-with-hand-a-valid-goal)

Other questions:

- [Own Goal adds to Career Stats? [closed]](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15306/own-goal-adds-to-career-stats) - *Edit rejected by @Ale and approved by @CodeNewbie and @Nicholas V. Then the tag still was removed by @Ale*, but then readded by @Nij again.
- [If a player has 3 goals, but one of them is own goal, is it called a hat trick?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/11930/if-a-player-has-3-goals-but-one-of-them-is-own-goal-is-it-called-a-hat-trick) - *Edit rejected by @Ale and @CodeNewbie*
- [Punishment for Own Goal](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/11821/punishment-for-own-goal) - *Edit rejected by @Ale and @CodeNewbie*

Do you think that the tag `own-goal` should be created? If yes, shouldn't it be applied to the aforementioned questions?

Comment: In my opinion, I don't think the tag should be created. You state that it's "an interesting aspect in many sports" though the questions you list are about football (soccer - which I'm not very knowledgeable in so I shall delegate). What would be examples from other sports that would necessitate this tag? From [this meta post](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/grounds-of-tag-creation), tags are encouraged to be created when they are necessary. You have stated your case for creating the tag, so let's see what others have to say on the matter.

Comment: As I am monogamous in terms of sports I'm mostly dealing with football questions. But a simple search resulted in [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Own_goal#Other_sports), and we can see from there that own goal is a general case in many popular team sports. But as you said, let's see some opinions from others too.

Comment: Reading the answer below and the referenced wiki page, I wouldn't mind if the tag is kept. My hesitation came from the tag being superfluous, but there is reasonably scoped application, it appears. That said, I wouldn't call "own goal" in other sports a "general case" but more of a "fringe case" (as some sports require "deliberate sabotage" for such an occurrence).  It may be more common in football (soccer) and hockey, but is presented as possibilities in other sports.

Comment: Update: I've edited usage guidance and the tag wiki pending review; have used it on a new Q&A as further example; and added the tag to three older questions (one where it's actually the only tag that makes sense!).

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts you put into establishment of this tag. Awesome job!

Comment: I am the user who delete the *own-goal* tag because in my opinion this is not a common event in sports. I am not sure on [this table](http://www.worldfootball.net/alltime_goalgetter/champions-league/eigentore/1/)  source, but it shows that own-goal in so rare in football. In my opinion this is not an interesting/useful tag, and I deleted it thinking of doing the right thing, but if many users would like to have it it is OK also for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The own goal has effects on statistics tracking, tactics and strategy, sports psychology, and even in rules. It (or its absence) is an interesting aspect of many sports, even those where we do not think of 'own goal' in the way that football or hockey can. For example, there are at least two [basketball](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basketball) questions asking about whether points are awarded for sinking an own basket, and who gets them.

I note that two people voted acceptance of the tag's addition to one of the questions, and I reverted its removal afterward because it circumvented the process of community review. So that is four different people who by direct action, have supported the creation of the tag.

Comment: Since you have mentioned basketball, do you suggest that *own basket* would also fall under ([tag:own-goal]) tag. (I guess that when a creation of a new tag is discussed, we should also look at specifying what questions would belong to this tag and - at least if there is possibility that it is not clear from the tag name - created at least some short tag-excerpt, where a guidance on when to use this tag should be explained.) I see that basketball is also mentioned in Wikipedia article [Own goal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Own_goal) (along with some other sports).

Comment: Yes, just as I was attempting to propose that [tag:laws] become a synonym redirected to [tag:rules].

Comment: Since the synonym between [tag:laws] and [tag:rules] is unrelated to this meta question, I'd suggested that we could continue this discussion elsewhere (if needed), perhaps [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2433/2017/4/7).